# How to display a Google Maps info window on the right side in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I would like to **display a custom infoWindow to the right of the marker that has been tapped**.

Per default, the info window is displayed at the top of the info window with

```
let anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0).
```

In order to display my info window at the right side, I have to anchor it to the right bottom of my marker. So I changed the info window anchor point like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! { 

    //load info window from xib
    //let infoView = ...
    let infoWindowAnchor = marker.infoWindowAnchor
    let newAnchor = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0)
    marker.infoWindowAnchor = newAnchor
    //...

    return infoView       
}
```

But since the info window's bottom is centered around the marker's anchor point, I have to increase the info markers x position by **0.5 * infoMarker.width** and readjust the camera if neccessary. I have no clue how to do this.

Basically I'm looking for the iOS way of adding an offset to the info window (comparable to pixelOffset in the JS API).

Comment: Are you suggesting for the anchor pointing down, it will point to the left for the info window to look at at the right side? The [GMSMarker: infoWindowAnchor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#a6668957ca7b6857355ee6cd9ab944a92) may be a bit of help as you'll specify the point in the icon image at which to anchor the info window, which will be displayed directly above this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up infoWindowanchor at any point can work for example while creating marker(if infowindow is of same size for all)
Following worked for me:

```
        let marker1 = GMSMarker()
        marker1.position = coordinatesLocationOne
        marker1.title = "US"
        marker1.snippet = "US"
        marker1.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 2.5, y: 2.5)
```